# json to java pojo with a map via GSON

Tags: javascript, json, gson

My java pojo looks like this

```
public class myPersonTO{
  String name;
  String surname;
  Map<String, Double> categories;

}
```

I am using the gson library, however I an not sure what my json stringn, and the object it is created from should like; I am using json stringify, on a javascript object containing two strings and an array of objects, see pseudo code :

```
var json = [];
jsonObject = new Object();
jsonObject.name = "testname"
jsonObject.surname = "testsurname"
var categories = [];

for(index=0,index <10;index++){
    var category = new Object();
    category.key = getKey();
    category.value = index;
    categories.push(category);
}
jsonObject.categories = categories;
json.push(jsonObject);
json = JSON.stringify(json); //convert json object, then use in submit
```

and then in Java I am usign the following :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<myPersonTO>>() {}.getType();
List<myPersonTO> myPersonTOList  = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,listType);
```

Any help gratefully received. Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think the JSON verson of one of those objects would look like:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "surname": "Scum",
  "categories": {
    "whatever": 22.5,
    "balloons": 107.0023,
    "zebras": -10299.01
  }
}
```

*edit* — OK in response to the extensive changes in your question: your "categories" object should **not** be an array. It should be a plain object, as in my example. Well, at least that's what I'd imagine it should be. I'd have to check this "gson" thing to make sure, but I'd be kind-of surprised to learn that it wants Java Map instances to be represented as arrays (surprised to the extent that I'd find another library).

Comment: gson is googles library for handling json objects, its part of guava.

Comment: Yes thanks, I found it - I was not able to determine from the "user guide" whether maps are encoded as arrays of key/value pairs. I'd still be surprised to learn that they are.

Comment: they may well not - still getting my head around json formatting. thnx for your help.